# MySQL & ColdFusion confusion

Tags: mysql, apache-flex, coldfusion, flash-builder

I have a query that was created to retrieve some data from a MySQL server and the query works great when running it directly on the server. When I run the query through a program like Sequel Pro it retrieves the data just fine as well. However, when inserted into a ColdFusion `.cfc` function, it retrieves all of the data except the timestamp field. I can't figure out why for the life of me. Here is the query followed by the CF Function.

```
SELECT tbl_names.*, max(tbl_timestamps.tstamp)
FROM tbl_names LEFT JOIN tbl_timestamps
ON tbl_names.name = tbl_timestamps.name
GROUP BY tbl_timestamps.name

<cffunction name="recent_timestamp" output="false" access="remote" returntype="any" >
    <cfset var qAllItems="">
    <cfquery name="qAllItems" datasource="TimeClock">
        SELECT tbl_names.*, max(tbl_timestamps.tstamp)
        FROM tbl_names LEFT JOIN tbl_timestamps
        ON tbl_names.name = tbl_timestamps.name
        GROUP BY tbl_timestamps.name
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn qAllItems>
</cffunction>
```

When I run the application, when the `.cfc` function is called it pulls all of the data except the time stamps. Here is the error that Flash Builder gives me:

"The returned object contains an invalid property name "max(tbl_timestamps.timestamp)". If you are using a database query which uses a group function, then try using an alias in the query for this group function. Any thoughts on how I can fix this? I've tried just about everything I could find. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused. How are you running the query from Flash Builder?  Do you mean ColdFusion Builder?  What happens if you run a simple CF program to create an instance of the CFC and run that method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just give alias for max(tbl_timestamps.tstamp) and it should work. I guess you are working on flex/flash project where you are calling CFC function remotely. Actually this is not an ColdFusion error but Flex/flash build not able to parse query with column name max(tbl_timestamps.tstamp) so giving alias will solve this issue.

Your query may look like below.

```
        SELECT tbl_names.*, MAX(tbl_timestamps.tstamp) AS maxtstamp
        FROM tbl_names LEFT JOIN tbl_timestamps
        ON tbl_names.name = tbl_timestamps.name
        GROUP BY tbl_timestamps.name
```

Comment: You are a scholar and a gentleman. It worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised the query doesn't error out whenever you run it because your select clause has tbl_names.* while your group by clause has tbl_names.name.  To fix it, change one of those so they match.

As far as an alias for max(tbl_timestamps.tstamp) goes, while you don't necessarily need one for the query to run in ColdFusion, you will need one if you want to do anything with that field, such as display it.

Comment: you'll also want to give the `max(tbl_timestamps.tstamp)` an alias as well

Comment: Yes, the query is wrong. There the group by field name and select field name are not matching.

Comment: @Abhisek - No, mySQL allows you to omit some columns from the `group by`. (Though it can be convenient, it can also produce unexpected results if you are not careful.)